# What's wrong with my RewriteRule? It seems ok, but it doesn't work

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a rewrite rule on my webpage.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php?p=$1 [L]
```

I want it to work so it rewrites URLs like this:

```
http://example.com           -> index.php
http://example.com/home      -> index.php?p=home
http://example.com/lol       -> index.php?p=lol
```

But when I use the following php code inside my index.php

```
print_r($_GET)
```

It gives this:

```
Array ( [p] => index.php )
```

It gives this same results in all URLs (I tried these: `http://example.com`, `http://example.com/`, `http://example.com/about`, `http://example.com/about/`

Can you help me debig this?

Comment: What? `mod_rewrite` off-topic here? We even have a tag wiki!

Answer (score 0):

I got it figured out:

The correct code is this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)/?$ index.php?p=$1  [NC,L]
```

Sorry for the question.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that your rewritten URL still matches the rule and you get a new rewrite:

```
http://example.com/home
http://example.com/index.php?p=home
http://example.com/index.php?p=index.php
```

Since the `[QSA]` flag is not set, the new `p` parameter replaces the previous one. (I'm not fully sure about why you don't get an infinite loop, I suppose mod_rewrite makes a check to avoid useless redirects).

You need to add additional conditions. For instance, you can make a rewrite only if the URL does not match a physical file or directory:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?p=$1 [L]
```